# ember-cli: Copying js files into dist without importing them

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a javascript file that I use with a Worker in my Ember app. Thus, I want the javascript file in my `dist` directory, but I do not want to run it in the web app itself- in short, I want to be able to treat the script like any non-javascript asset using `app.import()`.

Is there a good way to do this? I can't seem to find a proper way to do it in the ember-cli documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the file in the [`public`](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#raw-assets) folder. It will be copied over as is.